# 'Nonetype' is not callable

Tags: python

```py
print ("Hello!")
print
print ("I will tell you what age you will be in 25 years time")

age=int(input("How old are you? "))

age = age + 25
print ("Your age in 25 years would be ") + (str)age (" years")
```

On line nine where the print is, I am trying to add the age into the print statement and it says that the 'NoneType' is not callable. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you get a little `^` character that exactly points to the error? ... Is it `(str)age`?

Comment: `(str)age` makes no sense in Python. I'd suggest running through a structured tutorial, see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F.

Comment: What version of python. I get a different error: SyntaxError on `str(age) ("years")` which needs a plus sign

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use C-style type conversions here; that doesn't really work in Python. I recommend you "forget" about C-syntax and other languages you may already know, and learn Python from first principles, as Python has many differences from C and C-style languages, and applying those assumptions in Python will get you in trouble :-)

Answer (score 2):

`(str)age` isn't how you cast something like a string. You have to do it as `str(age)`.

Also, your `print` statement was wrong

This is how it should be:

```
print ("Hello!")

print ("I will tell you what age you will be in 25 years time")

age=int(input("How old are you? "))

age = age + 25 

print ("Your age in 25 years would be " + str(age) + " years")


# output
Hello!
I will tell you what age you will be in 25 years time
How old are you? 26 <------ user input
Your age in 25 years would be 51 years
```